# respuesta fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

consulta: estoy realizando una consulta api por medio de fetch. Como pueden observar lo estoy haciendo con una función y quiero retornar los valores de la respuesta. Sin embargo,  la promesa de responseData se pueden ver la data en la consola pero el retorno a la función principal trae toda la promesa con la respuesta. Agradezco me den una mano a saber como puedo retornar la respuesta como si lo mostrara por consola.

```js
function peticiones(url,datos){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    //headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    headers.append('GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS');
    return fetch(url, {
      headers: headers,
      cache: "no-cache",
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(datos)
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.ok) {
          return response.json();
      } else {
          throw new Error('Server response wasn\'t OK');
      }
    })
    .then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
        return responseData;
    });
```

[image: respuesta responseData]

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que se te puede resumir bastante, pero de igual manera ignoro las acciones que tengas los headers que agregas :( de todas maneras te adjunto este código simulando un url y los datos, yo le asignaría una variable afuera como lo muestro, o dentro pero no retornar dentro de la promesa sino una vez que tenga.
Espero se entienda y sobre todo poder haberte ayudado

```js
/* Este sería un ejemplo de tu codigo

const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
let responseComplete = [];
const datos = "no sé";

function peticiones(datos) {
  //let responseComplete = [];
  fetch(url, {
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    cache: "no-cache",
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(datos),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => responseComplete = responseData);

  //return responseComplete;
}

peticiones(datos);

*/

//Algo así saldría
function refrescar(){
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(resUser=>{
        console.log(resUser);
    });
   }
   refrescar();
```

Comment: Si claro, se puede resumir bastante. Pero no es el proposito por X posición a nivel de negocio. La pregunta va enfocada hacia la respuesta que genera. Lo que busco es que la respuesta se pueda retornar para así crear una clase exclusiva y apuntar todas mis peticiones allá. Colocando el return me lleva toda la promesa y lo cual no es manejable a mi parecer.